# REGEXP_REPLACE replacing text with the same text in lower case

Tags: plsql, regexp-replace

I am trying to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` in PL/SQL to replace some text with the same text in lower case. Actually, the rule is that I want all text between `"()"` that has only one char to be in lower case.

Here is an example :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
  'i want what what is between <> in lower case : I am a test(E) (A) (HELLO)'
  , '(\(\D\))', '<\1>'
) FROM DUAL
```

### Result :

```
I want what is between <> in lower case : I am a test(e) (a) (HELLO)
```

or this because I am a little confuse about my exercice:

```
I want what is between <> in lower case : I am a test<(e)> <(a)> (HELLO)
```

How can I get my text in lower case ? I tried in several ways but I can't get out with it. I don't know hot to tell `REGEXP_REPLACE` to put `"\1"` content in lower case.

Thanks you for your help.

Best regards.
MS

Comment: Maybe you could reread your question as there is some confusion between `(` `)` characters and `<` `>`.

Comment: Instead of caps lock and bold text use code blocks, it is much better accepted by community and  whole humanity as well

Answer (score 0):

(with `Oracle11g`) Here is how to replace the first occurrence:

### Use `REGEXP_instr` and `REGEXP_substr` to be able to apply `lower` to the matched pattern

```
 SELECT substr(it, 1  , REGEXP_instr( it,  '(\(\D\))')-1)
     ||lower(          REGEXP_substr(it,  '(\(\D\))')  )
     ||substr(it,      REGEXP_instr( it,  '(\(\D\))')+3, length(it))
FROM (SELECT 'i want what what is between <> in lower case : I am a test(E) (A) (HELLO)' it from dual) ;
```

and if you want the weird `<>` around it:

```
 SELECT substr(it, 1  , REGEXP_instr( it,  '(\(\D\))')-1) 
 || '<'
     ||lower(          REGEXP_substr(it,  '(\(\D\))')  )
 || '>'
     ||substr(it,      REGEXP_instr( it,  '(\(\D\))')+3, length(it))
FROM (SELECT 'i want what what is between <> in lower case : I am a test(E) (A) (HELLO)' it from dual) ;
```

I think you cannot have recursive regexp in Oracle. So if you want to be able to replace 2 occurrences:

```
SELECT substr(rit, 1 , REGEXP_instr( rit,  '(\([[:upper:]]{1}\))')-1) 
     ||lower(          REGEXP_substr(rit,  '(\([[:upper:]]{1}\))')  )
     ||substr(rit,     REGEXP_instr( rit,  '(\([[:upper:]]{1}\))')+3, length(rit))
from (
(SELECT substr(it, 1 , REGEXP_instr( it,  '(\([[:upper:]]{1}\))')-1) 
     ||lower(          REGEXP_substr(it,  '(\([[:upper:]]{1}\))')  )
     ||substr(it,      REGEXP_instr( it,  '(\([[:upper:]]{1}\))')+3, length(it))  rit
FROM (SELECT 'i want what what is between <> in lower case : I am a test(E) (A) (HELLO)' it from dual))
) ;
```

(+ I replace the `\D` by `[[:upper:]]{1}` which is more accurate)

Answer (score 0):

To bad this has to be such a difficult problem! Seems like it would be easy.

To handle a variable number of occurrences of the pattern, you need to loop through the string looking for them.  Maybe someone will come up with a slick solution using `CONNECT BY` or something but in the meantime and since you are using PL/SQL why don't you go old-school and create a function that does it?  It will arguably be easier to maintain and will be wrapped up in a reusable unit available for all to use too.  Pass it a string and have it return the cleaned up version.

```
SQL> select lower_single_letters('I want what is between in lower case : I am a test(E) (A) (HELLO)') text
    from dual;

TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I want what is between in lower case : I am a test(e) (a) (HELLO)

SQL>
```

Here's some sample code since I wanted an example for use in my utility package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function lower_single_letters(string_in varchar2) return varchar2 is 
  tmp_string             varchar2(1000) := string_in;         -- Holds the string
  regex_pattern constant varchar2(20)   := '\([[:upper:]]\)'; -- Pattern to look for '(A)'
  letter_offset          integer;                             -- Offset of the pattern
  letter                 varchar2(1);                         -- The letter to lower()
BEGIN
  -- Loop while the pattern is found in the string passed in
  while regexp_like(tmp_string, regex_pattern)
  loop
    -- Get the offset in the string
    letter_offset := regexp_instr(tmp_string, regex_pattern)+1;
    -- Get the letter
    letter        := substr(tmp_string, letter_offset, 1);
    -- Replace it in the string
    tmp_string    := regexp_replace(tmp_string, '.', lower(letter), 1, letter_offset);
  end loop;
  -- Return it when the pattern is no longer found
  return(tmp_string);
END lower_single_letters;
```